# Importing Vue-luxon for Vue v3 - this.$luxon is not a function error

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, luxon

I´ve tried everything I can think of to get vue-luxon working on my Laravel 8 / Vue 3 application, but failed misserably. I´ve followed these steps according to the docs:

```
npm install vue-luxon;
```

The docs doesn´t say where, but I placed this sentence in my app.js file:

```
import VueLuxon from "vue-luxon";
```

As I understand it, this line has to change to App.use(VueLuxon) and is also placed in app.js:

```
Vue.use(VueLuxon);
```

And (according to the docs), that´s it... I should be able to call:

```
this.$luxon("2020-10-05T14:48:00.000Z")
```

to display a formatted date, but instead I keep getting this error on the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.$luxon is not a function

Here´s the contents of my resources/js/app.js file:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './components/App.vue'
import VueLuxon from "vue-luxon";

createApp({
    components: {
        App,
    }
}).mount("#app")

App.use(VueLuxon)
```

And the contents of my js/components/App.vue file:

```
<template>
<div class="flex flex--column flex--align-center flex--justify-center">
    <div class="logos">
        <img src="../../static/img/laravel.png" width="240" alt="" />
        <img src="../../static/img/vue.png" width="240" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="title">
        <h1 class="vue">Vue 3</h1>
        <h1 class="plus">+</h1>
        <h1 class="laravel">Laravel 8</h1>
    </div>

    {{ this.$luxon("2020-10-05T14:48:00.000Z") }}

</div>
</template>

<script>
// import VueLuxon from "vue-luxon"; // I´ve tried importing luxon here... doesn't work either.

export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log("Component mounted.");
    },
};
</script>
```

I´ve tried placing the imports directly on the component, register as app components, or any possible combination, with the same results. I´m surely missing something, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you do not use "this." in template.

According to official repository, this plugin is NOT compatible with Vue 3, just with Vue 2 only (at least for now).

Source: https://github.com/casbloem/vue-luxon/issues/21

Solutions:

1. Wait for update.
2. Fork this repository (and make pull request after).
3. Since it is using luxon library under the hood, write own wrapper for it. https://github.com/moment/luxon
4. Find alternative for handling dates.

Comment: Upss.. Thanks @chojnicki, that's probably why, eh? I´m having a hard time finding libraries for Vue 3, I guess it´s too different and too new. As for the solutions: 1. Is not feasible, 2. and 3. Don´t know how to do that! :(., and 4. Any suggestions??

Comment: Never used luxon, but I'm using dayjs. Check if this fills your needs

Answer (score 8):

You can use globalProperties in vue 3:

In your main.js

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
app.config.globalProperties.$luxonDateTime = DateTime;
```

Then in your template:

```
<template>
{{ $luxonDateTime.fromISO("2020-10-05T14:48:00.000Z").toRelative() }}
</template>
```

You will get "6 months ago"

Comment: Thanks @Julio. I switched to dayjs after chochniki's suggestion and seems to be working fine, but your method may solve the issue for others and for other libraries as well. Cheers!

Comment: I defined this part const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
app.config.globalProperties.$luxonDateTime = DateTime;
in my app.js and I want to use $luxonDateTime in my component but I am getting error like this.$luxonDateTime is not a function

Answer (score 0):

For Vue3 you can try also:

```
import { App } from 'vue';
import {
    DateTime,
    Duration,
    Interval,
    ...
} from 'luxon'

type TLuxon = {
    DateTime: typeof DateTime,
    Duration: typeof Duration,
    Interval: typeof Interval,
    ...
} 

const luxon: TLuxon = {
    DateTime,
    Duration,
    Interval,
    ...
}

export default{
    install:(app: App) => {
        function load(): TLuxon{
            return luxon
        }
        app.config.globalProperties.$lx = load();
    }    
};

declare module "@vue/runtime-core" {
    //Bind to `this` keyword
    interface ComponentCustomProperties {
      $lx: TLuxon;
    }
}
```

Then in main.ts:

```
import luxonLoader from './modules/luxon/luxonLoader'
createApp(App)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .use(luxonLoader)
    .mount('#app')
```

And you can use luxon in any template:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    {{time}}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HomeView',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  computed: {
    time(): string{
      let currentTime = this.$luxeon.DateTime.now().toString()
      return currentTime
    }
  }
});
</script>
```